# What's Adapter.getItem() for?

Tags: android, adapter

I am writing a custom adapter for use with a `ListView`.

The `Adapter` interface includes a `getItem()` method which returns, according to the docs, an `Object` as

> the data item associated with the specified position in the data set.

What's this object supposed to be? I can only imagine the `ListView` wants to call either `toString` or `equals` on it, since there's not much else you can do with a raw `Object`. But I don't have a convenient `Object` I can return, and in any event I'm overriding `getView` so the ListView has no need for a String from my dataset anyway.

Can I just return `null` or something else completely irrelevant?

Comment: Checkout this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6711592/2482894

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If each item in the ListView represents some object, say a String, then you can return the String here. This is useful for your controller layer if it needs to be able to perform some logic when, eg. the user taps that item in the ListView.

Returning null is fine as the usage is up to you.

I've personally never returned anything but null here.

Comment: So, whatever I return is what's passed back to me if I call getItemAtPosition, etc. I get it. Thanks.