# What is the intent of the methods getItem and getItemId in the Android class BaseAdapter?

Tags: android, adapter

I'm curious about the purpose of the methods [`getItem`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItem%28int%29) and [`getItemId`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItemId%28int%29) in the class Adapter in the Android SDK.

From the description, it seems that `getItem` should return the underlying data.  So, if I have an array of names `["cat","dog","red"]` and I create an adapter *`a`* using that, then *`a.getItem(1)`* should return "dog", correct?  What should *`a.getItemId(1)`* return?

If you've made use of these methods in practice, could you provide an example?

Comment: +1 Excellent question. I want to point out that `getItemId()` in `ArrayAdapter()` always returns `-1` with `assert false : "TODO";  return -1;`

Answer (score 87, accepted):

I see these methods as a cleaner approach to accessing my list's data. Instead of directly accessing my adapter object via something like `myListData.get(position)` i can simply call the adapter like `adapter.get(position)`.

The same goes for `getItemId`. Usually I would use this method when I want to execute some task based on the unique ID of an object in the list. This is especially useful when working with a database. The returned `id` could be a reference to an object in the database which I then could perform different operations on(update/delete/etc).

So instead of accessing the ID from the raw data object like `myListData.get(position).getId()` you can use `adapter.getItemId(position)`.

One example of where i've felt like I needed to use these methods was in a project using the [SeparatedListViewAdapter](http://jsharkey.org/blog/2008/08/18/separating-lists-with-headers-in-android-09/). This adapter can contain multiple different kinds of adapters, each representing data of a different type(typically). When calling `getItem(position)` on the `SeparatedListViewAdapter`, the object returned may be different depending on which "section" the position is that you send it.

For example, if you had 2 sections in your list(fruit and candy): If you used `getItem(position)` and `position` happened to be on an item in the **fruit** section, you would receive a different object than if you requested `getItem(position)` with `position` pointing to an item in the **candy** section.  You might then return some sort of constant ID value in `getItemId(position)` which represents what kind of data `getItem(position)` is returning, or use `instanceof` to determine what object you have.

Other than what I've mentioned, I've never felt like I really needed to use these methods

Comment: for non-sql related adapters , will getItemId still have a purpose? if so , what should be returned? position?

Comment: the purpose or use of the method is mainly up to the developer and is not tied to a database driven app.  use it to your advantage to create clear/readable/reusable code.

Comment: i see . so this is why the description is so vague ? it's not in use by the API in any way  ,just like the getItem , right? the only things that the API uses are the getView and the getCount ?

Comment: Yeah i guess.  `getView`, `getCount`, `getViewTypeCount`, etc are used specifically for properly showing your listview UI.  the other functions simply help create implement other functionalities such as performing further actions upon clicking an item, etc.  although i often use `getItem` inside `getView`

Comment: So why a long and not an Object ? Mobile databases often use UUID as ids because of disconnected mode. Is it safe to not implement getItemId() ?

Comment: @NicolasZozol Sure- it's safe not to implement `getItemId`, just return `0L` or `null` and don't use it anywhere.  I don't see any obvious reason why a UUID would be more valuable than just some `long` value for ID.  Disconnected mode? What's that?

Comment: @binnyb: Nicolas meant that with UUIDs, it is still possible to create valid unique IDs (e.g. on your mobile device), even without having a network connection.

Comment: I use getItemId(position) as described above.  I just wanted to make sure (since this post is from 2011), that getItemId(position) is still for use by developers... and is not part of a more recent feature enhancement?

Comment: Is it allowed to return valid unique ID for items which have it and 0L for those which don't?

Comment: @Malachiasz sure, just be careful that items which have it would never have a 0L value....

Comment: @binnyb so it seems that 0L is treated as any other ID, so all items which don't have ID must look the same when they return 0L. Otherwise it won't work.

Answer (score 36):

Well, it seems that this question could be answered in a simpler and more straightforward way... :-)

Simply put, Android allows you to attach a `long` to any `ListView` item, it's that simple. When the system notifies you of the user selection, you receive **three** identifying variables to tell you what was selected:

- a reference to the view itself,
- its numeric position in the list,
- this `long` you attached to the individual elements.

It's up to you to decide which of these three is the easiest for you to handle in your particular case but you have all three to choose from all the time. Think of this `long` as a tag automatically attached to the item, only that it's even simpler and easier to read out.

The misunderstanding about what it usually does stems from a simple convention. All adapters have to provide a `getItemId()` even if they don't actually use this third identification. So, by convention, those adapters (including many in samples in the SDK or all around the web) simply return `position` for a single reason: it's always unique. Still, if an adapter returns `position`, this really means *it doesn't want to use this feature at all,* since `position` is already known, anyway.

So, if you need to return any other value you see fit, feel free to do so:

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
  return data.get(position).Id;
}
```

Comment: Nice explanation for this `getItemId()` ... What happen when/if this method is not overridden in your custom adapter?

Comment: Being marked abstract in the base class, you have to. Unless you override something that overrides the original adapter, of course. Try to leave it out, and if Eclipse complains then you have to. :-)

Comment: Thanks. I've always had this method commented out without warnings. I have a **CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CustomListItem>** with getCount(), getItem(...) and getView(...), using the "holder pattern". Just out of curiosity...

Comment: Yep, you can do that because **ArrayAdapter** extends **BaseAdapter** and already provides its own implementation.

Comment: And with a simple array, that's all right. But just consider another case, when you want to display items from a database, for instance. You will then probably extend **BaseAdapter** and you can use this long ID to store the database key. When the user selects something, you'll directly get back the key of the selected record via the *id* argument. You can then load it from the database right away, for instance. Only problem that you have to use numeric keys because Android decided on a long instead of something broader.

Comment: "this long you attached to the individual elements" ... "Think of this long as a tag automatically attached to the item" How does it get attached / where is it determined what this long will be? Specifically, what would SimpleCursorAdapter return from getItem()?

Comment: Is this a case where the developer would have to subclass the adapter and override getItem() to return what they want to?

Comment: To answer my question in regard to `SimpleCursorAdapter.getItem(n)` (inherited from CursorAdapter): it move its cursor to position n and returns the cursor. (I get this from reading the source code at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev/cursoradapter/src/main/java/androidx/cursoradapter/widget/CursorAdapter.java) Unfortunately CursorAdapter.getItem()'s documentation is not very helpful: "Get the data item associated with the specified position in the data set."

Comment: You mix `getItem` and `getItemId`. This question and all the answers are about the second. But if you move over to the id, yes, if the adapter you have at hand doesn't supply the id you'd prefer, subclass and modify it.

Answer (score 7):

The `getItemId` method is largely designed to work with Cursors that are backed by SQLite databases. It will return the underlying cursor's id field for the item in position 1.

In your case there isn't an id for the item in position 1: I'm assuming ArrayAdapter's implementation just returns -1 or 0.

EDIT: actually, it just returns the position: in this case `1`.

Comment: No it returns `-1`. Here is the implementation `assert false : "TODO";
return -1;`

Comment: As of Android 4.1.1, it returns position: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java#ArrayAdapter.getItemId%28int%29

Answer (score 5):

If you implement `getItemId`correctly then it might be very useful.

Example :

You have a list of albums :

```
class Album{
     String coverUrl;
     String title;
}
```

And you implement `getItemId` like this :

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position){
    Album album = mListOfAlbums.get(position);
    return (album.coverUrl + album.title).hashcode();
}
```

Now your item id depends on the values of **coverUrl** and **title** fields and if you change then and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your adapter, then the adapter will call getItemId() method of each element and **update only thouse items which id has changed.**

This is very useful if are doing some "heavy" operations in your `getView()`.

BTW : if you want this to work, you need to make sure your `hasStableIds()` method returns false;

Comment: This is a valuable observation, can you provide some data to back this selective update mechanism?

Comment: Why should `hasStableIds()` return false? It seems to me that the hashcode computed from the same string would return the same value every time, which is a stable ID according to [the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#hasstableids).

Comment: consider that using hashCode may return true to two Strings

Answer (score 4):

I would like to mention that after implementing `getItem` and `getItemId` you can use [ListView.getItemAtPosition](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getItemAtPosition%28int%29) and [ListView.getItemIdAtPosition](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getItemIdAtPosition%28int%29) to directly access you data, instead of going through the adapter. This may be particularly useful when implementing an onClick listener.

Comment: This is indeed extremely useful if you have a header on your listview and the positions passed to the click handler are off by one

Answer (score 1):

`getItem` or `getItemId` are few method mainly designed to attached data with items in the list. In case of `getItem`, you can pass any object that will attach to the item in the list. Normally people return `null`. `getItemId` is any unique `long` value you can attach with the same item in the list. People generally return the position in the list.

What's the use. Well, as these values are bound to the item in the list, you can extract them when user clicks on the item. These values are accessible through `AdapterView` methods.

```
// template class to create list item objects
class MyListItem{
    public String name;
    public long dbId;

    public MyListItem(String name, long dbId){
        this.name = name;
        this.dbId = dbId;
    }
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// create ArrayList of MyListItem
ArrayList<MyListItem> myListItems = new ArrayList<MyListItem>(10);

// override BaseAdapter methods
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // return actual object <MyListItem>
    // which will be available with item in ListView
    return myListItems.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // return id of database document object
    return myListItems.get(position).dbId;
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// on list item click, get name and database document id
my_list_view.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        // extract item data
        MyListItem selectedItem = (MyListItem)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);      
        System.out.println("Your name is : " + selectedItem.name);

        // extract database ref id
        long dbId = id;

        // or you could also use
        long dbId = parent.getItemIdAtPosition(position);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

in case your adapter ui change according to position use this two methods

```
@Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }
```