# why and when should i use getItemId

Tags: android, adapter

hi i am using a list fragment that is populated from a `simpleCursorAdapter`.

At `onCreateContextMenu` and `onContextItemSelected` i need the name of the list item and the id respectively. I am getting the correct results with these commands:

```
AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
String name =  ((Cursor) adapter.getItem(info.position)).getString(1).toString();
```

and

```
 ((Cursor) adapter.getItem(info.position)).getInt(0).
```

the cursor from the query has first returned column `_id` and second `name`.(explaining getString(1),getInt(0)).

My question is why and when should i use `getItemId`. What should i get?

Comment: may be of use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6711592/what-is-the-intent-of-the-methods-getitem-and-getitemid-in-the-android-class-bas

Comment: see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6711592/what-is-the-intent-of-the-methods-getitem-and-getitemid-in-the-android-class-bas