# IndexOutOfBoundsException in getItemId in Android baseAdapter

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter, baseadapter

I have a custom base adapter to work with my ArrayList of customObjects. There's a small chance that my data set is changing in the background when the user enters my listView and it seems to be causing my IndexOutOfBoundsException. I'm currently doing:

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {

    return custom.get(position).getID();

}
```

Should I just stick to returning the position from like ArrayAdapter?

```
/**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
```

I could just catch this error, but I'm not sure what to do in the catch. I need to return something, but I'm afraid to return something like -1 or 0.

In this question: [What is the intent of the methods getItem and getItemId in the Android class BaseAdapter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6711592/what-is-the-intent-of-the-methods-getitem-and-getitemid-in-the-android-class-bas)

People say that ArrayAdapter returns -1, but that's not the case (as of March 2014 at least).

Answer (score 1):

Just check that your position is less than the size of the array, and return -1 if so.

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    if(position < custom.size()){
        return custom.get(position).getID();
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Don't believe you can return null when it is expecting a primitive.

Comment: Interesting. Do you know why this method even exists? Doesn't seem to be used for anything.