# Image Loading Library Picasso not loading image into imageview

Tags: android, picasso

I am trying to create android app with image gallery created with grid view using image adapter which fetch data using picasso library.but no image is displayed.It may be a problem of context or in picasso library but i am not sure where is the problem as i get no error.everything works fine according to Logs

```
**package com.example.android.popmovies;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public class PopMovieFragment extends Fragment {
    ImageAdapter imageAdapter;
    public PopMovieFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main,container,false);

        GridView gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridview);

        imageAdapter    = new ImageAdapter(getActivity(),new ArrayList<String>());

        gridView.setAdapter(imageAdapter);

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Log.v("check","ok");
            }
        });

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        updateMovies();
    }

    public void updateMovies() {
        FetchMovieTask movieTask = new FetchMovieTask();
        movieTask.execute();
    }

    public class FetchMovieTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String[]> {


        final String LOG_TAG = FetchMovieTask.class.getSimpleName();

        private String[] getMovieImageFromJson(String movieJsonStr)
                throws JSONException {

            ArrayList<String> movieResults = new ArrayList<>();
            String posterUrl;
            final String OWM_MOVIE_RESULTS = "results";
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(movieJsonStr);
            if (jsonObject.has(OWM_MOVIE_RESULTS)) {
                JSONArray movieArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray(OWM_MOVIE_RESULTS);

                //JSONArray movieArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray(OWM_MOVIE_RESULTS);

                for (int i = 0; i < movieArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject movieObject = movieArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    posterUrl = movieObject.getString("poster_path");
                    movieResults.add(posterUrl);
                    Log.v(LOG_TAG, posterUrl);
                }
                for (String items : movieResults){
                    Log.v(LOG_TAG,items);
                }



                // return null;
            }

            return movieResults.toArray(new String[0]);



            // Log.v(LOG_TAG,posterUrl);


        }


        @Override
        protected String[] doInBackground(String... params) {


            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            BufferedReader reader = null;


            String movieJsonStr = null;
            //parameters for api link will be here

            try {

                final String MOVIE_BASE_URL = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie";
                final String APPID_PARAM = "api_key";
                final String CRITERIA_FOR_MOVIE_SELECTION_TOP = "top_rated";
                final String CRITERIA_FOR_MOVIE_SELECTION_POPULAR = "popular";



                Uri builtUri = Uri.parse(MOVIE_BASE_URL).buildUpon()
                        .appendPath(CRITERIA_FOR_MOVIE_SELECTION_TOP)
                        .appendQueryParameter(APPID_PARAM, BuildConfig.OPEN_MOVIEDB_API_KEY)
                        .build();

                Log.v("TAG","BuiltURI" + builtUri.toString());

                URL url = new URL(builtUri.toString());

                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.connect();

                // Read input stream into a String

                InputStream inputstream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                if (inputstream == null) {

                    movieJsonStr = null;
                }
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputstream));

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    buffer.append(line + "\n");
                }

                if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                    movieJsonStr = null;
                }

                movieJsonStr = buffer.toString();

                Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Movie Json String" + movieJsonStr);


            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "error here" + e);

                movieJsonStr = null;
            } finally {
                if (urlConnection != null) {
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
                if (reader != null) {
                    try {
                        reader.close();
                    } catch (final IOException e) {
                        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "ErrorClosingStream", e);
                    }
                }


            }

            try {
                // here will be method call for JSon parsing.
                 String [] check_items = getMovieImageFromJson(movieJsonStr);

                for (String items : check_items){
                    Log.v(LOG_TAG,items+"new");
                }
                return  check_items;

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {

            if (result != null) {


                for (String resultItems : result){
                    Log.v(LOG_TAG,resultItems+"GoodLuck");
                    final String PICTURE_BASE_URL = "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/";
                    final String PICTURE_URL_END = resultItems;
                    Uri builtUri = Uri.parse(PICTURE_BASE_URL).buildUpon()
                            .appendPath(PICTURE_URL_END.replace("/",""))
                            .build();
                    Log.v(LOG_TAG,resultItems+"GoodLuck"+builtUri.toString());
                    imageAdapter.setmresultItems(builtUri.toString());
                }
            }
        }

    }
}



class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private Context mContext;
        private ArrayList<String> mresultItems;




        public ImageAdapter(Context c,ArrayList<String> resultItems){
            mContext = c;
            mresultItems = resultItems;

        }

        public int getCount(){
           // return mThumbsIds.length;
            return  0;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position){
            return  null;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position){
            return  0;
        }


    public void setmresultItems(String resultItems){
                mresultItems.add(resultItems);


    }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView imageView;

            if (convertView == null){
//            if it is not recycled, initialize some attributes
                imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
                imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85,85));
                imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                imageView.setPadding(8,8,8,8);

            }else{
                imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
            }
            //imageView.setImageResource(mThumbsIds[position]);
            for(String picResultUrl : mresultItems){
                Picasso.with(mContext).load(picResultUrl).into(imageView);


            }


            return  imageView;
        }



        //references to our Images

        //private Integer[] mThumbsIds ;





}**
```

Comment: Do a debug inside getView to see if Picasso is getting the picResultUrl's correctly. And I advise you to also set images for .error and .placeholder, to see if Picasso is giving an error itself, or it cannot get the image data and just showing a placeholder.

Comment: Picasso is not giving error what does it mean ?? does it mean that there is problem with picasso

Comment: Then you may be getting the picResultUrl wrong. Do a debug.

Comment: No result in debugger and log.v is also not working

Comment: So you are getting null values inside the for loop in getView? If so, is your mresultItems list populated up until that point?

Comment: mresultItems is populated and i have removed the for loop according to the answer of Daniel Nugent but no result and no log results are displayed inside getview method

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have a for loop in the getView() method, it already gets called for each item in the list.

Be sure to return the correct count:

```
    public int getCount(){
        return mresultItems.size();
    }
```

Then, use just the current position of the data source in getView():

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;

        if (convertView == null){
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85,85));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8,8,8,8);

        }else{
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        //modified:
        String picUrl = mresultItems.get(position);
        Picasso.with(mContext).load(picUrl).into(imageView);
        }

        return  imageView;
    }
```

Also, call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter in `onPostExecute()` after the data source of the adapter has been updated:

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {

        if (result != null) {
            for (String resultItems : result){
                Log.v(LOG_TAG,resultItems+"GoodLuck");
                final String PICTURE_BASE_URL = "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/";
                final String PICTURE_URL_END = resultItems;
                Uri builtUri = Uri.parse(PICTURE_BASE_URL).buildUpon()
                        .appendPath(PICTURE_URL_END.replace("/",""))
                        .build();
                Log.v(LOG_TAG,resultItems+"GoodLuck"+builtUri.toString());
                imageAdapter.setmresultItems(builtUri.toString());
            }
            //Add this here:
            imageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is one problem mostly i find getItem(position) in programs but u have written mresultItem.get(position)

Comment: @Pheonix I just updated the answer with one more thing, be sure to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter when the data source is changed or updated.  As for `getItem()`, that is one way to do it, but in your `getItem()` override, you return null, and just access the data source directly in `getView()`.  Either way works.  See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6711592/what-is-the-intent-of-the-methods-getitem-and-getitemid-in-the-android-class-bas

Comment: i have tried your solution still no success  @Daniel Nugent

Comment: Post your current code in a Gist (gist.github.com) and post the link here, I'll take a look.

Comment: Right before the call to `imageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`, log the value of `imageAdapter.getCount();` and make sure it's what you expect.

Comment: It is showing value 20 which is equal to count of 20 links provided after JSON parsing so i think it is as expected as it will show 20 images in the grid view using imageview   @Daniel Nugent

Answer (score 0):

I found that i was not returning view in onCreate method which was the root cause of blank screen.