# Changing child view color of recyclerview android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In my android Application, I added a recyclerview to show list of printing items. Each item view represents an information to print and also has a button to do printing. Print button color is light blue before printing and will change to yellow after printing . (printing code will execute here )

So, I clicked first print button and printed, button color was also changed to yellow . It is still okay to here. But, the problem is after scrolling to some distance, I found some buttons also changed color to yellow although it is not printed.

**Here is my ViewHolder where I changed print button color in onClick() method.**

```
public class IB17InventorySearchViewHolder extends BaseViewHolder<IB17InventorySearchResponse> {
    @BindView(R.id.tv_location)
    TextView tvLocation;
    @BindView(R.id.tv_tuNo)
    TextView tvTuNo;
    @BindView(R.id.tv_sku)
    TextView tvSku;
    @BindView(R.id.tv_lot_no)
    TextView tvLotNo;
    @BindView(R.id.tv_qty)
    TextView tvQty;
    @BindView(R.id.btn_print)
    Button btnPrint;
    IB17InventorySearchResponse inventorySearchResponse;
    private Activity mActivity;

    public IB17InventorySearchViewHolder(View itemView, Activity mActivity) {
        super(itemView);
        this.mActivity = mActivity;
    }

    @Override
    public void setData(IB17InventorySearchResponse data) {
        this.inventorySearchResponse = data;
        tvLocation.setText(data.getLoccode());
        tvTuNo.setText(data.getTuno1());
        tvSku.setText(data.getSkucode());
        tvLotNo.setText(data.getLot4());
        tvQty.setText(String.valueOf(data.getQty()));
        btnPrint.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.btn_print) {
          if(BluetoothPrintHelper.printSucess)
            btnPrint.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#fff111"));

        } else {

            // for whole itemview click

        }
    }
}`
```

**Here is my Adapter**

```
public class IB17InventorySearchRecyAdapter extends BaseRecyclerAdapter<BaseViewHolder, BaseModel> {
private List<IB17InventorySearchResponse> searchResponseList;
public Context context;

public IB17InventorySearchRecyAdapter(Context context, List<IB17InventorySearchResponse> searchResponseList) {
    super(context);
    this.context = context;
    this.searchResponseList = searchResponseList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public BaseViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.ib17_search_result_row, parent, false);
    return new IB17InventorySearchViewHolder(view, (Activity) context);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(BaseViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.setData(searchResponseList.get(position));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return searchResponseList.size();
}}
```

My Question is **how should I change child view(button) color of viewholder in recyclerview without impacting other itemview childs(viewholder buttons)** Any ideas or alternative ways are appreciating!

Comment: add boolean flag that stores the state of your button and set color of button based on its value.

Comment: Later asking this question, I found a great article for handling viewstate in recycler view https://android.jlelse.eu/android-handling-checkbox-state-in-recycler-views-71b03f237022

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is, add a boolean field to PoJo class of which the list is composed of. By default they all will be false. And when you'll press the print button set the value to true and notifies the adapter for the data change. Now set if that field is true then color will be Yellow else Green (or whatever you set).

Comment: Comparing this to my answer I like this one more. Seems like the easier way of doing it.

Comment: Thanks @Ashutosh, i will try it now.

Answer (score 2):

This is because of how RecyclerView works. It recycles your view after it disappears from your screen. If you want to maintain the state of a view, you could keep track of it in a List. Example code for in your adapter:

```
private ArrayList<Integer> idsOfAllItemsThatHaveBeenPrinted = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then after the thing has been printed, you can add some identifier to the list

```
idsOfAllItemsThatHaveBeenPrinted.add(1);
```

now back in your `onBindViewHolder` you can check if your `searchResponseList.get(position)` is in that ArrayList. If it is in the ArrayList, change the background color to blue. If it **IS NOT, then change it to yellow**

```
IB17InventorySearchResponse x = searchResponseList.get(position)
if (idsOfAllItemsThatHaveBeenPrinted.contains(x.identifier)) {
// change to blue
else {
// change to yellow
}
```

Comment: Thanks @ZUNJAE, let me try.

Comment: You can have more idea about this subject : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6711592/what-is-the-intent-of-the-methods-getitem-and-getitemid-in-the-android-class-bas

Comment: it bad practice to solve this problem like this, you should use pojo class with a boolean , instead of making whole new list, which will increase time and space complexity by O(n).

Comment: The way the RecyclerView works is it loads the model from the ArrayList and it recycles its views. This ArrayList is read only. Changing the value (your so called class with a boolean) on a model from this ArrayList doesn't mean the ArrayList gets updated.