# Use of methods getItemViewType and getItemId of Recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I had a problem: when i clicked a checkbox of single item in recycler view, other item's checkboxes also got selected....But when i overided these two methods and returen position with it,problem was solved....
So my question is how did they solve my problem???

Already know what is written in android documentation.

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

Comment: they actually tell which item is clicked by passing the position from the list

Comment: getItemId has to return a unique value

Comment: weird, have you added if else checks in ViewHolder? Because it is not enough to use 'if' only

Comment: i think notification of previously selected element is also necessary along with if else

Comment: When you want to define HeaderView and ChildView in adapter, You can use getItemViewType.Where getItemId is unique id of your single item in adapter.

Answer (score 1):

getItemViewType() is mainly used when you want show different types of view based on your position .

Let say you have a chat adapter , sender user chat should comes in right while receiver user chat should comes in left . In such  scenrio , you can use getItemViewType (based of user id , you can show the different views)

getItemId()  :  We usually use this , when we try to do specific task for particular item .  For getItemId you may check this . [What is the intent of the methods getItem and getItemId in the Android class BaseAdapter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6711592/what-is-the-intent-of-the-methods-getitem-and-getitemid-in-the-android-class-bas)